# Cells gets overlapped and painted when Scroll happens in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Initially I display data in cells as user scrolls I need to load more data in DataGridView.

I am using DataGridView CellPainting for drawing lines.
When I start scrolling in datagridview the cells get overlapped and it completely changes the output.

```
public partial class Display : Form
{
    public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    // To create the rows and columns and fill some data
    private void LoadData()
    {
        int columnSize = 10;

        DataGridViewColumn[] columnName = new DataGridViewColumn[columnSize];

        for (int index = 0; index < columnSize; index++)
        {
            columnName[index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            if (index == 0)
            {
                columnName[index].Name = "Name";
                columnName[index].HeaderText = "Name";
            }
            else
            {
                columnName[index].Name = (index).ToString();
                columnName[index].HeaderText = (index).ToString();
            }
            columnName[index].FillWeight = 0.00001f;
            columnName[index].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnName[index]);
        }

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < columnSize; rowIndex++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add((rowIndex + 1).ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = (rowIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rectPos1 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
        Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        Graphics graphics = this.dataGridView1.CreateGraphics();
        Point[] points =
        {
                new Point(rectPos1.Left , rectPos1.Bottom), 
                new Point(rectPos1.Right, rectPos1.Bottom),
                new Point(rectPos1.Right, rectPos1.Top)
        };
        graphics.DrawLines(graphPen, points);
        e.PaintContent(rectPos1);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[Sample Download Link](http://1drv.ms/1PX09Rr)

Which I have shown in the below image

[image]

How can i avoid it please help me solve this issue.

Comment: can you please post the actual code and not a link? have you also tried stepping through the code using the debugger..? perhaps you are using the incorrect EventHandler to do your displaying

Comment: sorry MethodMan, forgot to post the code. I have updated the original post

Comment: I tried debugging buy no idea why it's repainting again during scrolling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of issues.  First and foremost, you should almost always use the provided Graphics object you get from the PaintEventArgs.  CreateGraphics is a temporary canvas that gets easily erased.  One of the parameters you get is the CellBounds rectangle, so you can use that.  Your lines are actually drawing outside of the rectangle, and you aren't clearing the previous contents, so your code should look something like this:

```
Rectangle rectPos1 = e.CellBounds;
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectPos1);
Graphics graphics = e.Graphics; // this.dataGridView1.CreateGraphics();
Point[] points =
  {
    new Point(rectPos1.Left , rectPos1.Bottom - 1), 
    new Point(rectPos1.Right - 1, rectPos1.Bottom - 1),
    new Point(rectPos1.Right - 1, rectPos1.Top)
  };
graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, points);
e.PaintContent(rectPos1);
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks LarsTech,   this is what I wanted